# jQuery clone with radio

Tags: php, jquery, post, clone

I have trouble to `$_POST` radio and radio selection if i use jquery `clone` method.

Below code i have **Gender** selection. If user can click on add-more link clone gender and append to same form.

**HTML**

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<div id="one">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="1" />Male<br />
    <input type="radio" name="gender"  value="2" />Female<br />
</div>
<div id="appendBefore"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="addMore();">Add More</a>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addMore(){
    var copy_ = $("#one").clone();
    copy_.insertBefore('#appendBefore');
}
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
print_r($_POST);
```

> Q - 1. Radio not checked properly.
>
> Q - 2. Radio not posted properly in php.

Thanks.

Comment: check these : http://jsfiddle.net/Tz66H/4/

Comment: Thanks. It is working after change radio box name. But how to get it in `PHP` because it is not an array.

Comment: Thanks @MeeraTank now it is working after adding hidden element. When post form iterate the name+increment value through `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="1" />Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="gender"  value="2" />Female<br />
```

You can only check one radio with in a same group (**having the same name**). In your case when you clone and append the radio's, the new group is also having the same name, that's why you can only select one from all the radio's.

To resolve this, you have to make the radio's name different for each group. Maintain a counter like thing with the name and every thing will be fine.

Ex:

```html
<p>
Block 1
</p>
<input type="radio" name="gender1" value="1" />Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="gender1"  value="2" />Female<br />
<p>
Block 2
</p>
<input type="radio" name="gender2" value="1" />Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="gender2"  value="2" />Female<br />
```

[JSFiddle with proposed solution](https://jsfiddle.net/vebpmpte/)

Comment: Thank you it is working but how to get it in PHP $_POST because it is dynamic.

Comment: You have to iterate the name + increment value to get it in $_POST